# Cannot retrieve column in SAP Hana Studio

Tags: hana, hana-studio

I am importing a .csv file using HANA studio, this is what my table looks like:

[image: Preview Of Imported Table]

This is what my query looks like:

```
select outage_start from "PIHPJ"."ji_major_storm"
```

and this is the error message:

```
SAP DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name: OUTAGE_START: line 1 col 8 (at pos 7)
```

If I change to upper case:

```
select OUTAGE_START from "PIHPJ"."ji_major_storm"
```

I still get this error message:

```
SAP DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name: OUTAGE_START: line 1 col 8 (at pos 7)
```

What’s going on???  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a common challenge and there are plenty of questions and answers for it.

In short: if an object has been named with double quotation marks (`" "`) then the name is **not** converted to upper case.

To address such objects (tables, columns, views, etc.) it is necessary to use double quotation marks again.

If, for example, the column was named `"outage_start"`, you will have to use the quotation marks and the lower case every time you use this column.

So this:

```
select "outage_start" from "PIHPJ"."ji_major_storm"
```

might work in your case.

Comment: Thank you @Lars Br., renaming the column RENAME COLUMN "PIHPJ"."ji_major_storm"."outage_start" TO OUTAGE_START also seems to help. Do we know why SAP does this?

Comment: Of course we know why SAP does this: it's part of SQL standard and implemented in other RDBMS like Oracle for decades. The main reason is to avoid identifiers that are the same as reserved words (e.g. a table called `sELect` should be avoided).

Comment: And of course that has been documented for SAP HANA... https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/209f5020751910148fd8fe88aa4d79d9.html#loio209f5020751910148fd8fe88aa4d79d9___bsql_introduction_1sql_introduction_identifiers